# vb.net 2010 console application command line aguments

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a small automation program that will run as a scheduled task. I want to be able to either pass a command line argument to it or not. I have the argument part working, but if I run it with out any arguments, nothing happens.

I am using

```
Dim CommandLineArgs As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String) = My.Application.CommandLineArgs`
```

along with

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CommandLineArgs.Count - 1
    Dim arg As String = ""
    arg = CommandLineArgs(i)`
```

Then, based on the argument that is passed, I have an If/Then statement to perfom the task. I would like for it to run a predetermined task if there is no argument passed, or to present a message with the usage syntax.

How can I have it check if an argument was passed prior to trying to parse the arguments?

Adding full code...

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
Dim CommandLineArgs As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String) = My.Application.CommandLineArgs
Sub Main()
    Dim strfilename As String
    Dim num_rows As Long
    Dim num_cols As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim strarray(1, 1) As String

    'Load the file
    strfilename = "library.csv"

    'Check if file exist
    If File.Exists(strfilename) Then
        Dim tmpstream As StreamReader = File.OpenText(strfilename)
        Dim strlines() As String
        Dim strline() As String

        'Load content of file to strLines array
        strlines = tmpstream.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)

        ' Redimension the array.
        num_rows = UBound(strlines)
        strline = strlines(0).Split(",")
        num_cols = UBound(strline)
        ReDim strarray(num_rows, num_cols)

        ' Copy the data into the array.
        For x = 1 To (num_rows - 1)
            strline = strlines(x).Split(",")
            For y = 0 To num_cols
                strarray(x, y) = strline(y)
            Next
        Next
    End If
    For i As Integer = 0 To CommandLineArgs.Count - 1
        Dim arg As String = ""
        arg = CommandLineArgs(i)
         If arg.ToLower() = "/setup" Then
            Dim form As New frmAdmin
            Try
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'add logging
            End Try

        ElseIf arg.ToLower() = "/destiny" Then
            'argument test
            MessageBox.Show(CommandLineArgs(i))
            Try
                'code
            Catch ex As Exception
                'logging
            End Try
        ElseIf arg.ToLower() = "/ic" Then
            'argument test
            MessageBox.Show(CommandLineArgs(i))
            Try
                'code
            Catch ex As Exception
                'logging
            End Try
        ElseIf arg.ToLower() = "/adadd" Then
            'argument test
            MessageBox.Show(CommandLineArgs(i))
            Try
              'code
            Catch ex As Exception
                'logging
            End Try
        ElseIf arg.ToLower() = "/adremove" Then
            'argument test
            MessageBox.Show(CommandLineArgs(i))
            Try
             'code
            Catch ex As Exception
              'logging
            End Try
        ElseIf arg.ToLower() = "/help" Then
            'argument test
            MessageBox.Show(CommandLineArgs(i))
            Try
              'code
            Catch ex As Exception
              'logging
            End Try
        ElseIf arg.ToLower() = "/automate" Then
            'argument test
            MessageBox.Show(CommandLineArgs(i))
            Try
              'code
            Catch ex As Exception
               'logging
            End Try
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please use /help to see usage")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: you arent showing the relevant code you are using.have tried, so it is hard to say what we cant see isnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Main method in a module, and set the project startup to Sub Main, defining the array of string that will contain the command line arguments.

Then check for the length of the array

```
Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)

   If args.Length > 0 Then

   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this by using `       Dim Args = My.Application.CommandLineArgs.ToArray()
        If Args.Length > 0 Then...`

Comment: CommandLineArgs is a List, so the .Count property works. You don't need to convert to an array to get the length.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a helper method for me along time ago, which extracts the value of a swtich or returns if present or not -  this will help you maybe.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// If the arguments are in the format /member=value
    /// Than this function returns the value by the given membername (!casesensitive) (pass membername without '/')
    /// If the member is a switch without a value and the switch is preset the given ArgName will be returned, so if switch is presetargname means true..
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Console-Arg-Array</param>
    /// <param name="ArgName">Case insensitive argname without /</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string getArgValue(string[] args, string ArgName)
    {
        var singleFound = args.Where(w => w.ToLower() == "/" + ArgName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (singleFound != null)
            return ArgName;


        var arg = args.Where(w => w.ToLower().StartsWith("/" + ArgName.ToLower() + "=")).FirstOrDefault();
        if (arg == null)
            return null;
        else
            return arg.Split('=')[1];
    }
```

**Example**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        var modeSwitchValue = getArgValue(args, "mode");
        if (modeSwitchValue == null)
        {
            //Argument not present
            return;
        }
        else
        { 
            //do something
        }
      }
```